# shadow maps and standard gl matrix variables?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I actually have two question.

I am learning OpenGL and I encountered that many samples in internet pass view matrix, projection matrix and model matrix or combination of them to shader. I want to know why? Because you already have them from gl_modelview, gl_modelviewporjection and etc... so whats the use of passing them again as uniform to shader?

So anyhow I want to build a shadow map but I dont get it what to pass to shader to transform coordinates into shadow map. I prefer using standard gl_* matrixes as I already coded my program based on them.
Here is the code I have now.

```
void FirstPass()
{
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, shadow_fbo);
    glViewport(0,0,shadow_Width,shadow_Height);
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE); 
}

 void SecondPass()
 {
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT,0);
    glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE7);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,shadow_texmap);
 }

void display(void)
{
    glUseProgramObjectARB(0);
    float myarray[16];
    FirstPass();

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(light_positionFix[0], light_positionFix[1], light_positionFix[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
    DrawObjects();

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
    glLoadIdentity();

    SecondPass();

    if (!LightFollowCamera)
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_positionFix);

    gluLookAt(eye[0], eye[1], eye[2], lookat[0], lookat[1], lookat[2], 0, 1, 0);


    if (LightFollowCamera)
        {
            light_positionFix[0]=eye[0];
            light_positionFix[1]=eye[1];
            light_positionFix[2]=eye[2];
    }

    DrawObjects();

    glutSwapBuffers ();
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: Is there any reason in particular you are using the ARB GLSL extension and the EXT FBO extension? Both of these extensions are outdated and you should use core GLSL in OpenGL 2.0+ and core FBOs in OpenGL 3.0+.

Comment: No. Do you mean the glUseProgramObjectARB? I thought glUseProgramObjectARB and glUseProgramObject is same anyway.So whats the correct thing to do?

Comment: The correct thing would be to use `glUseProgram (...)`. When GLSL went core in OpenGL 2.0, they renamed some of the functions and did a lot of other minor things that are not worth mentioning - the short answer is pretend that the ARB extension never existed and follow the OpenGL 2.0 reference pages.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of these shader variables still work but are deprecated since OpenGL 3. For an up-to-date list of the existing built in variables take a look at page 7 of [this](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/reference_card/opengl43-quick-reference-card.pdf) monstrous pdf. Outdated variables aren't even mentioned there anymore. The pdf is for the very latest version of OpenGL which you shouldn't target as a beginner because you don't need all the cutting edge features. OpenGL 3.2 (core profile) is perfectly fine in terms of compability with 4.x, the support from graphics vendors and you'll find all the features you need as a beginner. Take a look at the [quick reference card](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/reference_card/opengl32-quick-reference-card.pdf). Old built-in variables are still mentioned in 3.2 but are marked as deprecated. The often used term *modern OpenGL* relates to OpenGL 3.x core profile or higher.